# My Junit test has given java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, maven, testing, junit

**This is the test class, It runs pretty well initially but after fixing some bugs from javax validation it started giving error**

**Actually I am new to JUnit testing and am very confused with this error I am getting. The error, Null Pointer exception. Please I will appreciate I some can lead me to solution **

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest
    class NhSystemApplicationTests {

        @Autowired
        private UserService userService;

        @Autowired
        private TaskService taskService;

    @Before(value = "")
    public void initDb() {
        {
        User newUser = new User("testUser@mail.com", "testUser", "****");
        userService.createUser(newUser);
        }

        {
        User newUser = new User("testAdmin@mail.com", "testUser", "*****");
        userService.createUser(newUser);
        }

        Task userTask = new Task("02/01/2018", "00:11", "11:00", "You need to work Today");
        User user = userService.findOne("testUser@mail.com");
        taskService.addTask(userTask, user);  
    }

    @Test
    public void testUser() {

        User user = userService.findOne("testUser@mail.com");
        assertNotNull(user);
        User admin= userService.findOne("testAdmin@mail.com");
        assertEquals(admin.getEmail(), "testAdmin@mail.com");
    }

    @Test
    public void testTask() {
        User user = userService.findOne("testUser@mail.com");
        List<Task> task = taskService.findUserTask(user);
        assertNotNull(task);
    }

    }
```

**Here is the image of the error java.lang.NullPointerException**
[image: stacktrace]

Comment: Reading the error message, it means some element of the ArrayList being parsed in the method testTask hasn't been properly initialized. It might be worthwhile looking into every related ArrayList to see if you have created them correctly.

Comment: Use your debugger to make sure that the two services got injected properly.  It looks to me like one of them might be null.

Comment: In your example It is not unit tests but integration tests. Please read differences between both then change your title question.